# How can I get the value of a picker and set it as an moc

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 entities: Category<-->>Transaction.

The category in my AddTransactionViewController is selected by a picker.

when I create a new transaction and try to set the transactionCategory (which is of a Category (Entity) class) with

`transactionCategory=[self.pickerCategories objectAtIndex:[self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0]]`*;

i get an error saying that I am passing a string to a ManagedObjectContext.  Any ideas on how I can get the picker selection as a NSManagedObject (Category)?

... I dont have a prepareForSegue method because I do not want it to change view controller when the save button is pressed, just clear the fields

Comment: please add the error log and more code. your question is not clear

Comment: @KingBabar the error log is reason: '-[__NSCFString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f60ab0,   which as I understand means I am passing a string as an moc.

Comment: The Transaction entity has a relationship with the Category entity, so when I save a new Transaction, i want to set the newTransaction.category parameter from the value of the picker

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to set NSString as a NSManagedObject.

try to set it as a property of your category instead

```
NSString *str = [self.pickerCategories objectAtIndex:[self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

Category *category = // ** your way of getting the NSManagedObject **//
category.text = str;

NSError *error = nil;
[category.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```